Is it possible to allow my chrome-extension to view html content of file URLs (file://) without the "Allow access to file URLs" setting being on?
I have a chrome extension that will look at the html content of any google page for specific bits of text. I use this extension to prevent students from going onto specific websites that the districts' firewall doesn't block.
My extension is capable of blocking certain files that students open locally onto the Google browser, but it can't unless the setting "Allow access to file URLs" has been selected by the students themselves (and I severely doubt they would do that voluntarily).
Is there any sort of API or something similar that would let me look at file URLS (file://) without needing the setting being turned on
Or is this something I should try to figure out with google admin?

Not a file:// URL per se, but you can use the new FileSystem API (showOpenFilePicker, showSaveFilePicker) in your extension's visible page or inside the offscreen document.

What would be the point of having a security setting if extensions could arbitrarily decide to ignore it?

Interesting, I'll check out the FileSystem API. Otherwise, I think I'm just going to figure out how to do something like this in Google Admin.
